# Positioning Devices (Intersecting Circles)

Tags: java, javascript, c, algorithm, math

I have a series of points, which represent mobile devices within a room. Previously I have systematically emitted a ping from each and recorded the time at which it arrives at the others to calculate the distances.

Here's a simple diagram of an example network.
[image: simple network]

**The bottom A node should have been a D instead**

After recording the distances I have the distance information in hashes.

```
A = {B: 2, C: 1, D: 3}
B = {A: 2, C: 2, D: 2}
C = {A: 1, B: 2, D: 2}
D = {A: 3, B: 2, C: 2}
```

My maths is rusty, but I feel like I should be able to then draw circles using these values as the respective  and then intersect the circles to calculate a relative graph of the nodes.

Every time I try to do it I start out with a series of circles drawn around the root node (in this case A) that looks something like this:

[image]

I know that the other nodes must lie on the lines that I have drawn around A, but without being able to position them, how do you draw their distances so that you may intersect the circles and create the graph?

Comment: On the first image the A node at the bottom, is actually D ?

Comment: Why do you have 3 separate language tags? :)

Comment: @GregKopff It's a language-neutral problem?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: then why put a language there at all ...

Comment: @Prince You have the distance between every pair of nodes. You can draw a graph out of it. Still what is that you exactly want? Do you want the Cartesian co-ordinates of each point on a 2d-plane?

Comment: The problem is not your maths being rusty; the problem is, you are trying to solve a hard problem. It certainly cannot be solved directly, using a closed-form equation.

Comment: @GregKopff In order to make the question visible to those who filter the question stream by their language(s).

Comment: @nitish712 I want the devices to be correctly relatively positioned. Cartesian coordinates would be great.

Comment: So you want the co-ordinates of each point on a plane?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to be able to create a virtual representation of the network in the first diagram.

Comment: @DanPrince You only have the relative distances. You don't know their relative directions (unit vectors). Hence IMO you cannot draw conclusions about their positions with this data.

Comment: You can just put your next node anywhere on its circle. Then you start positioning the other nodes using information from both. There isn't a unique solution as you can rotate 360 degrees around any of the nodes, the distances will still be the same.

Comment: An approx. plot is possible if you take all the data and not just for node A.

Comment: @alk Not sure that makes sense. How are you deriving the fact that two more coordinates need to be known?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with any one point say A. Now take the second point say B, and plot it somewhere on the circle with the center at A and radius as distance between A and B. Now take another point C.
Let the distance `(A,C)=x` and `(B,C)=y`. Find the point of intersection of the circles `(A,x)` and `(B,y)`. Mark it as `C`.

where circle `(P,q)` specifies center at `P` and radius `q`.

If no such point exists, then the given data is incorrect.

Now take the 4<sup>th</sup> point and similarly find the point of intersection of circles with centers at first three points and radii as distance between 4th and other three points respectively.     Apply this method until all the points are plotted.

Note that there can be infinitely many solutions as RobH pointed out. Since you need only a virtual representation, I guess anyone of the valid solutions suffices.

The above algorithm has an order of `O(N^2)`. It may be inefficient if the number of points are greater than 10000.

Also note that, to find the point of intersection of `k` circles, you first need to find the point of intersection for any two circles and validate these points on the remaining circles. This is because `k` circles can at most intersect at two points, assuming all have distinct centers.

EDIT: At any stage if there are two valid plots for a point, we can choose anyone of them and yet we arrive at one of the valid solutions.

Comment: Bear in mind that, at any time, the point you are trying to plot may have 2 solutions - you need at least 3 intersecting circles to calculate the position uniquely. It would be best to calculate the points with the biggest distances from A first.

Comment: Practical considerations make this a much harder problem than portrayed here: all measurements must be taken as *intervals* of valid distances (finite limits of precision). With your iterative approach this leads to the accumulation of error, easily ending up in the inability to place the next point. You should be tracking a *region* of available locations. The region gets more complex with each new point.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Agree with you. I thought it was intuitive to make such assumptions(regarding precision) while actually implementing the above algorithm.